# MySQL insert a new row only if a previous value in the row has changed

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to insert a new row into the database and then only if a previous value in the row has changed.

```
--
-- Table structure
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `macip` (
  `intId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `strPort` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `strIp` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `strVlan` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `strMac` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`intId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

--
-- Test data
--
INSERT INTO `macip` (`intId`, `strPort`, `strIp`, `strVlan`, `strMac`) VALUES
(1, 'Gig1/0/1', '192.168.100.8', '10', 'AA-BB'),
(2, 'Gig1/0/1', '192.168.100.8', '10', 'CC-DD'),
(6, 'Gig1/0/1', '192.168.100.8', '20', 'AA-BB');
```

- I have got a unchanging column **strPort**
- Next want do INSERT like this:
- First insert to database ('Gig1/0/1', '192.168.100.8', '10', 'AA-BB') = > do INSERT
- Next insert to database ('Gig1/0/1', '192.168.100.8', '10', 'AA-BB') => do not insert, exists
- Next insert to database ('Gig1/0/1', '192.168.100.8', '10', 'XX-EE') => do insert, changed MAC (or IP or VLAN or all this two/three values)
- Next insert to database ('Gig1/0/1', '192.168.100.8', '10', 'XX-EE') => do not insert, exists
- Next insert to database ('Gig1/0/1', '192.168.100.8', '10', 'AA-BB') => do insert, changed MAC (or IP or VLAN or all this two/three values), **but there is a problem in my SQL query, because this value exists in table, I need to compare with previous row with strPort**

This query doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO macip (strPort, strIp, strVlan, strMac)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Gig1/0/1', '192.168.100.8', '10', 'AA-BB') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT strIp, strVlan, strMac FROM macip WHERE 
    strIp = '192.168.100.8' AND strVlan = '10' AND strMac = 'AA-BB' 
    ORDER BY macip.`strPort` DESC LIMIT 1
) LIMIT 1;
```

I can't do a unique keys to columns, because SQL query return Exception.

Comment: Just build a unique index across the fields that you want to enforce only a single unique set of values for and handle the error.  Or possible do `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` approach.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to check changes against only the last inserted row with the same strport, not against _all_ rows in the table?

Comment: to Mike Brant: Hello, a unique constraint/index I don't want use, because if I call the database function from script, script returns error ($resSqlQuery = mysqli_query($this->LinkIdentifier, $strSqlQuery);). ON DUPLICATE KEY SET I can't use, because I need to store all historical data.

Comment: to Joachim Isaksson: Yes, I want check changes against only the last inserted row with the same strport

Answer (score 1):

How about just creating a `unique` constraint/index to prevent this problem?

```
create unique index idx_macip_strip_strvlan_strMac on macip(strIp, strVlan, strMac);
```

Then you can do the `insert` as:

```
INSERT INTO macip (strPort, strIp, strVlan, strMac)
    SELECT 'Gig1/0/1', '192.168.100.8', '10', 'AA-BB'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY SET strPort = VALUES(strPort);
```

The `ON DUPLICATE KEY` portion just prevents the `INSERT` from returning an error when there is a duplicate.

Comment: Hello, a unique constraint/index I don't want use, because if I call the database function from script, script returns error ($resSqlQuery = mysqli_query($this->LinkIdentifier, $strSqlQuery);). ON DUPLICATE KEY SET I can't use, because I need to store all historical data.

Comment: @czWolfHunter . . . Your comment makes no sense in the context of your question.  Your proposed query would prevent a row from being inserted, in the same way that this would prevent a row from being inserted.